# Is there a way to check for a gitlab merge request approval status and then trigger the next stage in CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, merge-request

I have a stage1 where it creates a merge request then after the merge request is approved by 3 approvers I manually trigger the stage2.
But, I want to find a way where I can check the merge request approval status created in stage1 and trigger the stage2 job automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this we will use the Gitlab API and the `jq` package.
Firstly, let's define the jobs.

`job_that_creates_mr` is the job that creates the merge request and has to wait for 3 approvers before triggering the `job_that_triggers_automatically_when_mr_approved`

In `job_that_creates_mr`, I assume that you use the gitlab API for it and specifically https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr

```
POST /projects/:id/merge_requests
```

In order to proceed we will need the `merge request id`, so adjust the way you create the mr, an example would be:

```
MERGE_REQUEST_IID=$(curl -XPOST -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests" --form "source_branch=<source_branch>" --form "target_branch=<target_branch>" --form "title=<mr_title>"  | jq '.iid')
```

By piping the result to `jq` we get the `merge request id`

Next we need to the `number of current approvers` for the mr with `iid` that we found previously, to get this we will use https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_request_approvals.html#merge-request-level-mr-approvals

```
GET /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/approvals
```

An example command would be:

```
NUMBER_OF_APPROVERS=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$MERGE_REQUEST_IID/approvals  | jq '.approved_by | length')
```

Now a template gitlab-ci.yml would be:

```
stages:
  - run_after_approval
  - create_mr


job_that_triggers_automatically_when_mr_approved:
  stage: run_after_approval
  script: 
    - echo 'I run automatically, even though it says manual'
  when: manual

job_that_creates_mr:
  stage: create_mr
  script: 
    - apk add curl jq
    - |
      MERGE_REQUEST_IID=$(curl -XPOST -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests" --form "source_branch=<source_branch>" --form "target_branch=<target_branch>" --form "title=<mr_title>"  | jq '.iid')
      NUMBER_OF_APPROVERS=0
      while [[ $NUMBER_OF_APPROVERS -lt 3 ]]
      do
        NUMBER_OF_APPROVERS=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$MERGE_REQUEST_IID/approvals  | jq '.approved_by | length')
        sleep 60
      done
      JOB_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/pipelines/$CI_PIPELINE_ID/jobs" | jq '.[] | select(.name=="job_that_triggers_automatically_when_mr_approved") | .id')
      curl -XPOST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/jobs/$JOB_ID/play"
```

**Note**: In this example change `job_that_triggers_automatically_when_mr_approved`, with your job name

The idea is that you have the ordering swapped so the `job_that_triggers_automatically_when_mr_approved` is `registered first` in the pipeline but as a `manual` job.

Then the job that create the merge request waits until the number of approvers is `3`, and then `plays` the `job_that_triggers_automatically_when_mr_approved`.

Comment: `    - |
      MERGE_REQUEST_IID=$(curl -XPOST -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests" --form "source_branch=<source_branch>" --form "target_branch=<target_branch>" --form "title=<mr_title>"  | jq '.iid')
      echo $MERGE_REQUEST_IID
      NUMBER_OF_APPROVERS=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token" $CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$MERGE_REQUEST_IID/approvals  | jq '.approved_by | length')
      echo $NUMBER_OF_APPROVERS
`
Hi, I got this error `ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1` after above